# what is the java's servlet equivalent on .net

Tags: java, .net

Please let me know what is equivalent of servlets in .net. The purpose of my question is to write a servlet or whatever it is on .net which just sends me a file when that URL is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708800/what-are-the-correspondent-of-servlet-and-applet-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want [HTTP handlers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001). This may be a duplicate.